# Error WordPress test Phpunit calling function in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

I'm testing with PhpUnit, calling functions of the functions.php

I have a function in which it verifies if it is a page and the SLUG template is equal to a page

```
function my_scripts() {

    var_dump (get_page_template_slug());

    if (is_page() && get_page_template_slug() == 'page-script.php') {

    ........
    }
}
```

In my test, I have this code

```
public function test_my_scripts(){

    $page_id = $this->factory->post->create(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
        )
    );
    add_post_meta( $page_id , '_wp_page_template', 'page-script.php' );
    add_filter( 'page_template', 'custom_page_template' );

    var_dump(get_page_template_slug($page_id));

    my_scripts();

}
```

The result of the var_dump of my test is

*string(15) "page-script.php"*

and that of the function of the functions.php

*bool(false)*

And do not enter the condition IF.

How can I establish that the call to the function that is from a page and the slug is indicated to enter the condition if?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution and it is to put this before the call to the function my_scripts();

```
$this->go_to(get_permalink($page_id));
```